# MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

i am new programmer in C# when i am connecting my asp.net web form app to mysql database on localhost

**i get this error:**

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

**why i need help**

i found something about that on stack but i dont know how to use their specific solution.

**about my code**

In my code i am trying to connect to mysql and call simple sql command
there is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebApplication2

{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                CheckMysqlConnection();
            }     
            UploadToMysqlDatabase();
            }

    private void CheckMysqlConnection() {

        //connection string

            string connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=ev3;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
            using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
            if(connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                    connection.Open();
                    Response.Write("Mysql Connection Succesful");
                }


            }


    }

    private void UploadToMysqlDatabase() {
        //Debug.WriteLine(objekt.portId);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM robot",connection);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ***// there is error***

        //connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**error detail**

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Connection must be valid and open.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
       v MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
       v MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
       v MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
       v MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       v MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       v WebApplication2.WebForm1.UploadToMysqlDatabase() v C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\infs1\insys2\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\WebForm1.aspx.cs:řádek 78
       v WebApplication2.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) v C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\infs1\insys2\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\WebForm1.aspx.cs:řádek 45
       v System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       v System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       v System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       v System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: your connection is disposed!

Comment: This comes from poor connection handling. But anyways, please add the actual error message to your question, including all relevant messages and inner exceptions.

Comment: And what i should do with disposed connection ?

Comment: @Johny.M nothing. you should use a valid connection when making a command.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Connection must be valid and open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `connection.Open()` is wrapped inside the `using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))` statement, it will automatically be disposed (no longer open for future use) once it has finished. You are trying to use a disposed connection in a completely separate method. What you need to do is either call the `private void UploadToMysqlDatabase()` method and pass the connection through as a parameter (ie. `private void UploadToMysqlDatabase(string conn)`, or create a new `connection.Open()` in your `UploadToMysqlDatabase()` method.

Comment: Connections are best not passed from method to method because it because difficult to make sure they're disposed of properly. Ideally if you need a connection, you create it right where you need it, wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)